# Quickbooks Sync Manager - REST service into data

Tags: integration, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We are using the Quickbooks Sync Manager to get our data onto the internet. We don't want to use the Web Connector anymore because we have been having issues with it and the applications running through it. I need to be able to read/write to the data put online by Sync Manager but I can't figure out how to get to it without going through the App center which doesn't support non SaaS applications... I just need my standalone code to get/send some data to/from Quickbooks from a web server.

Any tips on how to get started would be great. I can do REST services no problem... I just can't figure out how to connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do, isn't possible.

You should look through the Intuit Partner Platform FAQs:

- http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0080_FAQ

Specifically, pay attention to this one:

> Q: I want to integrate my custom (non-SaaS, single-tenant) solution
>   with Intuit Anywhere. Can I do this?
>
> A: Not today, but we are
>   considering it.

**If you're not SaaS, then you're not eligable to use the Intuit Partner Platform / Intuit Anywhere / Sync Manager.**

P.S.: The Web Connector is *way* less troublesome and *way* more reliable and Sync Manager. If you're having problems with the Web Connector you should ask on the forums about that - chances are you just need to tweak your scripts so they are more reliable, and that it's not actually a Web Connector problem.